# Dodge and Burn in Darktable

Tags: post-processing, effect, darktable

I was searching for Dodge and Burn in Darktable but didn't find any website that show how to do this. I've only found this feature request for darktable that show that the OP use Dodge and Burn and want some extra added to it. https://redmine.darktable.org/issues/12037

Does anybody know how can I dodge and burn in Darktable. Does it support this feature?

Answer (score 3):

You can use exposure module and it have something like layers (multiple instances) and each layer can have its own mask to change exposure only to selected area.

to create new instance (layer) you can use far right button in top left corner of the tool (next to enable/disable and reset buttons). To select specific area you can use blend mode with drawn mask, where you can use brush, circle, path or gradient. Second instance will look the same as original but it will have number next to the name.

The same layers are in other tools like Tone Curve that can also be used to Dodge and Burn.

You can read about multiple instances in the [Darktable manual](https://darktable.gitlab.io/doc/en/multiple_instances.html).